# Максимальное количество пересечений временных интервалов

Tags: sql, vertica

Есть таблица, в которой перечислены события с началом и концом действия. У событий есть различные типы. Нужно найти максимальное количество событий, которые происходили одновременно.

Пример таблицы:

| event_id | time_start | time_end | event_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-01 15:01:21 | 2022-10-01 15:03:21 | A |
| 2 | 2022-10-01 15:02:13 | 2022-10-01 15:03:10 | A |
| 3 | 2022-10-13 14:18:11 | 2022-10-13 15:07:01 | B |
| 4 | 2022-10-10 12:04:51 | 2022-10-10 12:06:28 | B |
| 5 | 2022-10-01 15:03:22 | 2022-10-01 15:05:43 | A |

Например, в этой таблице по типу А был момент когда одновременно действовали события id 1 и 2, а у типа B события не пересекались, т.е. результат будет такой:

| event_type | max() |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 1 |

В какую сторону копать, не понятно :(

BD - Vertica

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создадим таблицу и загрузим в нее данные. Id нас тут не очень будет интересовать.

```
create table events (
    time_start datetime,
    time_end datetime,
    event_type varchar
);

insert into events values
('2022-10-01 15:01:21', '2022-10-01 15:03:21',  'A'),
('2022-10-01 15:02:13', '2022-10-01 15:03:10',  'A'),
('2022-10-13 14:18:11', '2022-10-13 15:07:01',  'B'),
('2022-10-10 12:04:51', '2022-10-10 12:06:28',  'B'),
('2022-10-01 15:03:22', '2022-10-01 15:05:43',  'A');
```

---

Подумаем, как эту задачу можно решить на бумажке/календаре/гугл-календаре.  Можно для каждого события нарисовать в календаре полосу между началом и концом. События разного типа — разным цветом. Потом еще раз пройтись от начала до конца, записывая, сколько на каждый момент времени полос одного цвета. Достаточно делать это в тех местах, где начинается или оканчивается очередное событие. А потом из записанных сумм для каждого типа события найти максимум.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Осталось воспроизвести это в SQL.
Разобьем каждое событие на две отдельных строки: начало и конец. Кроме того, добавим столбец, обозначающий изменение количества событий. Начало будет  обозначать +1 к количеству событий, а конец -1. Остортируем по времени, чтобы получился возрастающий временной ряд.

```
select time_start as ts, event_type, +1 as cnt from events
union all
select time_end   as ts, event_type, -1 as cnt from events

ts  event_type  cnt
2022-10-01 15:01:21.000000  A   1
2022-10-01 15:02:13.000000  A   1
2022-10-01 15:03:22.000000  A   1
2022-10-10 12:04:51.000000  B   1
2022-10-13 14:18:11.000000  B   1
2022-10-01 15:03:21.000000  A   -1
2022-10-01 15:03:10.000000  A   -1
2022-10-01 15:05:43.000000  A   -1
2022-10-10 12:06:28.000000  B   -1
2022-10-13 15:07:01.000000  B   -1
```

Теперь нужно для каждой строки найти сумму всех значений cnt выше неё с с разбивкой по отдельным `event_type`. Это делается при помощи running/cumulative sum. В Vertica — [analytic sum](https://www.vertica.com/docs/10.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Analytic/SUMAnalytic.htm?tocpath=SQL%20Reference%20Manual%7CSQL%20Functions%7CAnalytic%20Functions%7C_____34):

```
select ts, event_type, cnt, sum(cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY event_type ORDER BY ts) as cnt_cum from (
    select time_start as ts, event_type, +1 as cnt from events
    union all
    select time_end as ts, event_type, -1 as cnt from events
) e1

ts  event_type  cnt cnt_cum
2022-10-01 15:01:21.000000  A    1  1
2022-10-01 15:02:13.000000  A    1  2
2022-10-01 15:03:10.000000  A   -1  1
2022-10-01 15:03:21.000000  A   -1  0
2022-10-01 15:03:22.000000  A    1  1
2022-10-01 15:05:43.000000  A   -1  0
2022-10-10 12:04:51.000000  B    1  1
2022-10-10 12:06:28.000000  B   -1  0
2022-10-13 14:18:11.000000  B    1  1
2022-10-13 15:07:01.000000  B   -1  0
```

Осталось найти максимальные значения среди `cnt_cum` для каждого `event_type`:

```
select event_type, max(cnt_cum) from (
  select ts, event_type, cnt, sum(cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY event_type ORDER BY ts) as cnt_cum from (
    select time_start as ts, event_type, +1 as cnt from events
    union all
    select time_end as ts, event_type, -1 as cnt from events
  ) e1
order by ts
) e2 group by event_type;

event_type  max
B   1
A   2
```

Comment: Апплодирую стоя, шикарное решение